# В каких случаях более предпочтителен NoSQL, чем SQL?

Tags: база-данных, nosql

В каких случаях используется NoSQL, потому что на мой взгляд, и там, и здесь, можно почти одинаково строить одну и ту же структуру. И если можно, просто пример реальных проектов.
Список интересующих меня:

- MongoDB
- Cassandra
- Redis
- Riak

P.S. В любом случае, получил ответ или нет, удаляю свой вопрос в течение 2 дней.

Comment: Лучше сначала разберитесь какие NoSQL вообще бывают. Тотже Redis никак не сможет заменить Mysql или PostgreSQL, это inmemory key-value база (более продвинутый аналог memcache). Утверждать что это одно и тоже как то странно.

Comment: Ладно, промашку дал. Но знаю про NoSQL в общих чертах. Только хотел бы узнать, в каких случаях NoSQL используется и больше ничего.

Comment: NoSQL решения надо использовать на больших объёмах данных, если у компании нет денег на покупку oracle :) Приемущество - быстрый поиск и выборки по сравнению с SQL-решениями на больших данных. Частые недостатки - нереляционность: отсутсвие JOIN-ов и группировок, частая неподдержка NoSQL адаптеров в разных ORM. А вообще вопрос хороший, только породит большие дискуссии - что SO не приветствует, не закрывайте, просто приведите конкретику - какая задача стоит, что использовалось ранее для БД, или что хотите разработать.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр Мне не нужна дискуссия. Поэтому я закрою этот вопрос в любом случае. А так, спасибо за пояснение. А спрашивал по этой теме [IFS - an Internet File System implementation based on Web services and peer-to-peer technology](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2918/IFS-an-Internet-File-System-implementation-based-o). Просто решил переписать этот проект с C++ на C#, а в качестве базы данных решил выбрать NoSQL.

Comment: @GhostBasenji хорошее решение, удачи :) Только помните про join и group - то что с SQL делается просто, с NoSQL может потребовать шаманств и больше времени прогеров. Обычно используют одновременно и SQL и NoSQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну вы, конечно, сравнили Redis и MongoDB...

Redis, всё же, больше для вещей, которые не надо хранить на диске и не так жалко потерять. 
Применять можно:

- Как кеш, аля Memcached.
- Хранить там профили/сессии.
- Для хранения промежуточных результатов вычислений.
- Etc...

Мы его лично используем для хранения токенов в системе авторизации и для хранения рейтингов игроков в нашей онлайн игре.

MongoDB ж - это полноценная СУБД с хранением на диске. Да, у Redis тоже можно выгрузку сделать на диск, но тогда скорость теряется.

Когда использовать NoSQL? Для начала нужно понять, когда хорошо использовать SQL? Когда данные структурированы и легко ложатся на модель кортежей.

Если же данные имеют привычку менять схему/структуру, то можно использовать NoSQL. Единственное, что у NoSQL баз проблемы с ACID (транзакциями, атомарностью и т.п.). 
Мы для онлайн игры используем NoSQL базу RethinkDb, к примеру, так как профили игроков постоянно меняются (их структура), сложно было бы такое хранить в классической релиционной СУБД.

Comment: MongoDB в каких случаях используется? Мне самому показался неразборчивой из-за того, что можно все свалить в одну кучу. Поэтому и возник вопрос, в каких проектах он пригодится.
Хм, Redis -- спасибо за ответ. Решил строить вроде распределенную файловую систему ради интереса. Мне понравился твое замечание по Redis. Буду его использовать. Поэтому и спрашиваю, как, что и где используется NoSQL :)

Comment: @GhostBasenji если схема данных изменчива - то NoSQL подойдёт. Но, ещё раз, там часто проблемы с транзакциями. Где-то их вообще нет.

Comment: Вот то, о котором я говорил [IFS - an Internet File System implementation based on Web services and peer-to-peer technology](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2918/IFS-an-Internet-File-System-implementation-based-o) Вот на основе этого я бы написал funny-проект.

Comment: @GhostBasenji вы это ради интереса/опыта делаете? Просто, почему бы не взять тот же Hadoop, к примеру?

Comment: Мда, впервые узнал про Hadoop. Буду изучать его. А вообще я хотел бы понять структуру и работу технологии WCF, переписав проект с C++ на C# из вышеприведенной статьи :)